# TabbedViewNavigator from Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, blackberry-playbook

How can I instantiate a TabViewNavigator from actionscript for the playbook? Currently, I add the necessary spark frameworks and have this piece of code in the Main of my actionscript project:

```
[SWF(width="1024", height="600", backgroundColor="#ffffff", frameRate="30")]
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var waitDialog:BaseDialog = new BaseDialog ();

    public function Main()
    {
        super ();
        var next:LabelButton = new LabelButton ();
        next.label = "Next";
        next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showTabs);
        this.addChild(next);
    }

    private function showTabs (event:MouseEvent):void{
        var temp:Stage = this.stage;
        temp.removeChild(this);
        var bar : TabbedViewNavigator = new TabbedViewNavigator();
        var tab1:ViewNavigator = new ViewNavigator();
        tab1.label = "Test";
        bar.addItem(tab1);
        temp.addChild(bar);
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, the button disappears as you would expect but the tab navigator is not added/does not appear. I tried without removing the `Main` class but that does not work either. What do I need to do to set up a tab interface. I can get similar code working through Flex and MXML but not in actionscript.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using MXML?

Comment: Mainly because the application is very data driven and it is difficult to manage a lot of data through flex as it does not let you pass data from view to view without an implicit cast (the data object) or static globals. If you have any other suggestions for solving this problem of flex, I would certainly like to know though as I am not too far in and I can certainly move over to flex.

Comment: I 'strongly' suggest looking into a Flex framework such as Swiz or PureMVC.  These frameworks add dependency injection, and IoC container, and greatly improved messaging/event handling - which is exactly what you need to pass data between views.  I used Swiz on a very large project (30 devs over 2 years) and it worked great.

Comment: Does setting x and y change anything?

Answer (score 0):

temp.removeChild(this); - this is the problem you just remove the movie clip form the stage. There is no sense in this row.